# check permission to see friends content

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

There is a way to check permissions for friend's content I can access through graph api/flq?

Example: get friend's links or statuses.

How can I access or check if I can access that contents?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the `permissions` connection on the current [User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) of your application like,

```
/me/permissions
```

to retrieve the list of permissions the User has granted to your application. From the output you can verify if you have the required [Extended Profile Properties](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/) permissions to get the status update or other information about friend.

For example presence of `friends_status` in output from end point will tell you that you can poll for User's friends status updates.

Quoting from [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) about data returned from `permissions` connection,

> array containing a single object which has the keys as the permission names and the values as the permission values (1/0) - Permissions with value 0 are omitted from the object by default; also includes a type field which is always permissions if the query param metadata=1 is passed.

**Edit**

As per discussion there can be three cases when you would retrieve no Post from current User's Friend

1. Current User denied the application `friend_status` permission. This case can be checked against the `/me/permissions` endpoint
2. User's friend has no Posts. Finding this out is difficult, assuming that its not an issue due to 1st case.
3. User's friend has denied applications access to his posts through the Privacy settings of Facebook. Finding this is also not possible assuming its not 1st case issue.

Comment: thank you.This permissions are linked to the app. If I would like to know the permissions just through the api ( with my access token frinds_status is 1)? I ask this because I can't get data for a part of my friends, not for all of them..

Comment: This maybe because their individual privacy settings. Check [this](https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/your-info-on-other#friendsapps)

Comment: just to reassume (cause maybe i was not so clear):
by calling a friend X
1)I can see X posts from facebook.com<br>
2)I can't see X posts (also with complete access token) from graph api because of his privacy settings.<br>
3)I can't see X posts ((also with complete access token) from graph api because of his privacy settings OR his non-permissions to my app.<br>

I'm right? There is a way to know, in the 3ed case, if the cause is permissions, privacy or X friend have 0 posts?

Thanks

Comment: I got your point. But finding out through Graph API whether the Friend of User has no post or issue with privacy settings would be difficult. As we can't query information about User's privacy settings.

Comment: I mean in the third case, in where I can make query from my app, there is a way to recognize, at least, two reason out of three? thanks

Comment: As for your case 3, you can know if the issue is with permission by querying `/me/premissions` end point but finding if Friend of User has no Post or has denied access through privacy settings is not possible.

Comment: Really clear, I'll check the permissions table to, at least, identify the first cause. thank you